# Running setup.py install for tesseract-ocr did not run successfully

Tags: python, pycharm, tesseract

So im trying to install Tesseract-OCR packages to this project for some personal scripts im trying to run and its not installing the packages.

Ever time I try to install Tesseract-OCR/give it the command e.g. pip install tesseract-ocr
its gives me this end of output, im using Python 3.9 and am on windows, i was expecting it to install so I could run my scripts [![pycharm terminal]

```py
(venv) C:\Users\bebla\PycharmProjects\osrs_basic_botting_functions>pip install Tesseract-OCR
Collecting Tesseract-OCR
  Using cached tesseract-ocr-0.0.1.tar.gz (33 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\users\bebla\pycharmprojects\osrs_basic_botting_functions\venv\lib\site-packages (from Tesseract-OCR) (0.29.32)
Building wheels for collected packages: Tesseract-OCR
  Building wheel for Tesseract-OCR (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      C:\Users\bebla\PycharmProjects\osrs_basic_botting_functions\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:726: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        % (opt, underscore_opt)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
      file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
      running build_ext
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\bebla\PycharmProjects\osrs_basic_botting_functions\venv\include -
IC:\Users\bebla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\bebla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include" "-IC
:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\P
rogram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tptesseract_ocr.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\tesseract_ocr.obj
      tesseract_ocr.cpp
      tesseract_ocr.cpp(779): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'leptonica/allheaders.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Tesseract-OCR
  Running setup.py clean for Tesseract-OCR
Failed to build Tesseract-OCR
Installing collected packages: Tesseract-OCR
  Running setup.py install for Tesseract-OCR ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for Tesseract-OCR did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      C:\Users\bebla\PycharmProjects\osrs_basic_botting_functions\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:726: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        % (opt, underscore_opt)
      running install
      C:\Users\bebla\PycharmProjects\osrs_basic_botting_functions\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      running build
      running build_py
      file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
      file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
      running build_ext
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\bebla\PycharmProjects\osrs_basic_botting_functions\venv\include -
IC:\Users\bebla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\bebla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include" "-IC
:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\P
rogram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tptesseract_ocr.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\tesseract_ocr.obj
      tesseract_ocr.cpp
      tesseract_ocr.cpp(779): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'leptonica/allheaders.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> Tesseract-OCR

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Answer (score 0):

simple answer is to Directly install tesseract-ocr from the directory its installed in if you downloaded the files from the internet, apparently tesseract cant be installed from pycharm on my pc, in terminal of pcharm in your project type the following: note it goes disk:\folder\Teesseract-OCR
then
pip install tesseract

```
C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR

C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR>pip install tesseract
```